How to run Workflow in .NET?
I'm using .NET 4.8 and VS 2017. In this legacy code I'm trying to run a workflow to create a Jira.
I get this exception :

Unable to create unknown type '{clr-namespace:Services.Modules.Asv.Workflows;assembly=Oddo.Services.Middleware.Modules.Asv.Business,
Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null}GetTicketByIdActivityAsync'
line number '110' and line position '16'.

I tried changing build action of my xaml file but in this line of code:
var activityDefs = Directory.GetFiles(".\\", "*.xaml", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(item => item.Equals(".\\CreateJiraMoboVLI.xaml"));

if (activityDefs == null)
{
      Logger.Error($"the activityDefs was null ");
      throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(activityDefs));
}

activitydefs is null.
after multiple clean and rebuild i get this errors:


I am failing to see what the two issues could have in common. I suspect they could be completely separate. For the null-Issue, I'd suggest to create a simple Console-App, that does only that, so you can investigate why it's null and how to fix it.

I found in an old thread that changing build action might resolve my initial problem

Then congratulations: You made progress to a different error :D

any idea about a fix for my initial bug ?

I seriously doubt that a random change would help at all. The error says that custom type can't be found. That means your application doesn't have a reference to the Oddo.Services.Middleware.Modules.Asv.Business assembly or the version it has doesn't have the namespace or type in the error. That's essentially the same as trying to use a missing type at compile time. You have to add a reference to that assembly

What exactly was that "changing build action" you did?

any idea about a fix for my initial bug always read the error. What you posted says there's an unknown type and mentions the namespace Services.Modules.Asv.Workflows and the assembly Oddo.Services.Middleware.Modules.Asv.Business. Do you have that assembly? Is there any type or method named GetTicketByIdActivityAsync in it?

@Fildor from "XamlAppDef" to "Resource"

i have GetTicketByIdActivityAsync is a class in the namespace "Services.Modules.Asv.Workflows"

Hmmm, I really doubt that fixes your issue. And I second Panagiotis in that it's probably one of the referenced (or the lack of reference to) packages. What version are your referencing? Mind that you need a version that's compatible with .NET Framework.

XamlAppDef was the wrong build type. That's used for WPF applications. Changing that to Resource tells VS this is just a file, which means you can build your code but the app will still fail due to the missing assembly. XAML is a format used by both WPF and Workflow Foundation that essentially serializes the classes you see in the form or workflow designer. When WPF or WF reads a XAML file it will try to create the types it sees defined in there. That's why you must add a reference to the missing assembly

still the same problem i changed build type to Resource did clean and rebuil and still the same errors, i checked and the assembly is referenced correctly
